# is %llx or %llu not supposed to work with wsprintf?

Tags: visual-c++, printf

I am using Visual Studio 2017 C++.  When I use printf with a specification such as %llx or %llu everything works as expected.  If I use the same format spec, %llu or %llx, with wsprintf, I get junk in the buffer instead of the result I had gotten with printf.

**My question is:** is there a way to get wsprintf to give the result that should be obtained when using %llx and/or %llu ?

Below is a very simple console program that demonstrates the different behavior of printf and wsprintf.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <inttypes.h>


int main()
{
  DWORD64 OffsetHWM = 0x7123456789012345;

  WCHAR   BufferBytes[256] = { 0 };  // initialized - no junk in there

  // the wprintf below works as expected

  wprintf(L"from wprintf : %8llX\n", OffsetHWM);

  // this call to wsprintf isn't filling the buffer with the expected value

  wsprintf(BufferBytes, L"%8llX\n", OffsetHWM);
  wprintf(L"from wsprintf: %s\n", BufferBytes);    // prints junk

  wprintf(L"\n");                                  // just for neatness

  wsprintf(BufferBytes, L"%8" PRIx64 "\n", OffsetHWM);
  wprintf(L"from wsprintf: %s\n", BufferBytes);

  // this truncates (as expected) the value of OffsetHWM - not useful

  wsprintf(BufferBytes, L"%8lx\n", OffsetHWM);
  wprintf(L"from wsprintf: %s\n", BufferBytes);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just don't use wprintf(), there is no point.  The only reason it still exists is allow programs to be ported that started life in 16-bit versions of Windows.  One of the many tricks they had to use to cram a graphical OS and its apps in 640KB of memory.  No long long back then.

Answer (score -1):

**wprintf()** should not be used any more, it is a Windows specific function which calls either **wsprintfA()** or **wsprintfW()** to do the actual work, both of which have the following note on their Windows Dev Centre Documentation site (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-wsprintfa):

**Note**  Do not use. Consider using one of the following functions instead: **StringCbPrintf, StringCbPrintfEx, StringCchPrintf,** or **StringCchPrintfEx**. See Security Considerations.